# Java still dont recognize horizontal scroll (right click) 14.04

Tags: java, openjdk, matlab, scrolling, trackpoint

I am totally trackpoint fan, I use it all the time and have disablet my touchpad. Due to my study I work a lot with MATLAB, but MATLAB uses Java, and horizontal scroll does not be recognized by java as I already reat in many other threats(well it recognizes as right click :S ). 
There seems to be no solution for that and disable horizontal scroll in matlab is no solution for me at all.

Does anybody know about a fix for that or somehow to enable horizontal scroll java. This really drives me crazy. HELP!

I have Ubuntu 14.04 with java version: 
java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

Thank you in advance!